# How to check if two date ranges overlap in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

In mysql, how can I check if two date ranges overlap?

I have this:

Note: We have that `p.date_started <= p.date_finished` but `dateA` can be equal to `dateB` or smaller than `dateB` or bigger than `dateB`.

CODE:

```
    $query = "SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.avatar_filename, p.id, p.user_id, p.address, p.topic, p.latitude, p.longitude, d.name AS department_name
              FROM user u
              JOIN placement p ON p.user_id=u.id
              JOIN department d ON d.id = u.department_id
              WHERE p.active=1 AND (('{$dateA}' BETWEEN p.date_started AND p.date_finished) OR 
                                    ('{$dateB}' BETWEEN p.date_started AND p.date_finished) OR
                                    (p.date_started BETWEEN '{$dateA}' AND '{$dateB}') OR
                                    (p.date_finished BETWEEN '{$dateA}' AND '{$dateB}'))";
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't know whether A is before or after B, and also not whether A-B can completely embed start-end or vice versa, then I think this is about as short and simple as it gets.

Comment: Um, time is linear, right? An event cannot end before it starts!

Comment: I did not say dateA and dateB is an event. They are simply two dates that can be in any order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we are guaranteed that `date_started`, `datefinished`, `$DateA` and `$DateB` are not NULL, and we're guaranteed that `date_started` is not greater than `date_finished`...

```
`s` represents `date_started`
`f` represents `date_finished`
`a` represents the smaller of `$DateA` and `$DateB`
`b` represents the larger of `$DateA` and `$DateB`
```

Visually:

```
      s-----f       overlap
 -----+-----+-----  -------  
  a-b |     |        NO
  a---b     |        YES
  a-----b   |        YES
  a---------b        YES
  a-----------b      YES
      a---b |        YES
      a-----b        YES
      a-------b      YES
      | a-b |        YES
      | a---b        YES     
      | a-----b      YES     
      |     a-b      YES
      |     | a-b    NO
```

We can easily detect when there's no "overlap" of the ranges:

```
( a > f OR b < s )
```

And we can easily negate that to return "true" when there *is* an "overlap":

```
NOT ( a > f OR b < s )
```

Converting that to SQL:

```
NOT ( GREATEST('{$dateA}','{$dateB}') < p.date_started
      OR LEAST('{$dateA}','{$dateB}') > p.date_finished
    )
```

Comment: If `greatest` returns the later date and `least` returns the earlier date, shouldn't it be  `NOT (GREATEST('{$dateA}','{$dateB}') < p.date_started   or  LEAST('{$dateA}','{$dateB}') > p.date_finished)` ?

Comment: @omega: yes, I got those backwards.  I've edited my answer. If any of those four values can be NULL, the condition will probably need to be modified to account for that.

Comment: `NOT ( a > f OR b < s )` is the same as `NOT ( a > f)  AND NOT (b < s )`. Which is the same as `a <= f  AND b >= s`. And this one can use an index range scan for one column.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: There's an equality predicate on another column in the table (`p.user_id = u.id`), so to get an index range scan, we'd want want a composite index with `date_started` (or `date_ended`) as the second column, with `user_id` as the leading column. If we have that, then yes, rewriting the predicates on date_started / date_finished columns would allow for a range scan operation.

Comment: It's also 5 bytes shorter :-)

Comment: You didn't cover where to-date in DB might be null ... please check the next answer!

Comment: @HusseinAkar:  i specifically noted at the beginning of this answer *"If we are guaranteed that date_started, date_finished, $DateA and $DateB are not NULL,"* ...  this answer was primarily concerned with explaining an approach, how we arrive at SQL constructs.

Comment: This answer also did not address handling of edge cases,  when `date_started` is equal to the end date of the range being checked... whether that is that an overlap or not? Slapping an `OR p.date_finished IS NULL` condition into the SQL makes sense, as long as a NULL value represents a point in the infinite future. We need to careful to note that assumption when recommending SQL constructs.  Because not every NULL value in every DATE column represents that.

Comment: @spencer7593 I didn't mention that your answer is wrong .. I told you that could be improved to cover the missing condition. Anyway, my other concern is using NOT in MySQL which always a performance issue in huge tables when using range scan over indexes or even worth when column not indexed.

Comment: @HusseinAkar  NULL value of date_finished is a "missing condition" that  needs to be fixed (as demonstrated in your answer) only if the NULL value represents a period that covers the entirety of the future. Then we could incorporate a condition. But we need to be careful gleaning that specific meaning to a row with a NULL value. It could also represent a period that can't have an overlap, or could represent a default value of one year, or one hour. i didn't delve into the details of handling all the edge cases. this answer focused on the question that was asked.

Answer (score 2):

## Logic that checks for overlap

`A -> B` represent one range and `a -> b` represent another range.

overlap scenario 1

A           B
*----------*
     a           b
     *----------*

overlap scenario 2

A           B
     *----------*
a           b
*----------*

overlap scenario 3

A           B
     *----------*
a                        b
*---------------------*

overlap scenario 4 - is when a or b is same as A or B

```
a == A || a == B || b == A || b == B
```

> Different scenarios would get fulfilled by checking against does four
>   scenarios.

Our logic should check for all scenarios.

```
(scenario 1 (+4) || scenario 2 (+4)  || scenario 3 )

(a >= A && a <= B) || (b >= A && b <= B) || (a < A && b > B)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cover all date overlapping cases even when to-date in database can possibly be null as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` t
WHERE t.`startDate` <= $toDate
AND (t.`endDate` IS NULL OR t.`endDate` >= $startDate);
```

This will return all records that overlaps with the new start/end dates in anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have one extra test. The first two statements will cover if the two ranges overlap on one end, or if the first range full falls within the second.

You will then need to test whether the second range is fully enclosed in the first, anything else will be covered in the first two tests. For that, you only need to test the start or the end.

Thus, I think this will work

```
 $query = "SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.avatar_filename, p.id, p.user_id, p.address, p.topic, p.latitude, p.longitude, d.name AS department_name
              FROM user u
              JOIN placement p ON p.user_id=u.id
              JOIN department d ON d.id = u.department_id
              WHERE p.active=1 AND (('{$dateA}' BETWEEN p.date_started AND p.date_finished) OR 
                                    ('{$dateB}' BETWEEN p.date_started AND p.date_finished) OR
                                    (p.date_started BETWEEN '{$dateA}' AND '{$dateB}'))";
```