# Get records between time range on 24 hours

Tags: mysql

I try to find pricing in my table according hours and duration.
For example, this is my table

```
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
| id | subscription_id | start_time | end_time | pricing |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
|  1 |               1 | 22:00:00   | 21:59:59 |     1.5 |
|  2 |               2 | 05:30:00   | 16:29:00 |    0.75 |
|  3 |               2 | 16:30:00   | 18:59:59 |    0.50 |
|  4 |               2 | 19:00:00   | 05:29:59 |     1.5 |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
```

Now, i've to find for subcription 2 that start at 16:00:00 and finish at 20:00:00
I tried several things like this without success

```
SET @startTime := '17:30:00';
SET @endTime := '20:30:00';

SELECT *
FROM subscription_detail_pricing sdp
WHERE (
    (start_time < end_time AND TIME(@startTime) BETWEEN start_time AND end_time)
    OR
    (start_time > end_time AND TIME(@startTime) NOT BETWEEN end_time AND start_time)
    OR
    (start_time < end_time AND TIME(@endTime) BETWEEN start_time AND end_time) 
    OR
    (start_time > end_time AND TIME(@endTime) NOT BETWEEN end_time AND start_time)
) AND subscription_id = 2;
```

I don't find query method for get my 3 records corresponding to this range

If someone can give some tips, i'm loosing myself -_-

Thanks for reading
BenWa

Comment: looks to me like there are only two rows that satisfy the conditions in the query, it doesn't look like there's any overlap with row id=2. Unrelated note: it seems like there's a 60 second gap. Consider `16:29:45`. And what about times that include fractional seconds? We could specify times with more precision :29.59:997 to make the gaps narrower. But there's still a gap. Normally, we would  specify `end_time` as the first point in time that is *after* the range, which in this case looks to match the beginning of the next range. And we can use `>=` and `<` comparisons in place of `BETWEEN`.

Comment: oh i see now, You mean that for `@startTime := '16:00:00' @endTime := '20:00:00'` the query misses (entirely skips over) row id = 3. Got it.

Comment: Hi @spencer7593 , indeed, i updated my table on a correct 24 hour lifecycle, begining at 00:00:00 and finish at 24:00:00 with end range to correct hour too (16:30:00 instead 16:29:29)
My main mistake was to have start hour greater than end.
I've more rows but i think queries are more easier now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a classic range overlap query..

If possible, you could save yourself a headache, split any ranges that wrap over `"00:00:00"` into two separate rows and make your `end_time`s exclusive

```
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
| id | subscription_id | start_time | end_time | pricing |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
|  1 |               1 | 00:00:00   | 24:00:00 |     1.5 |
|  2 |               2 | 00:00:00   | 05:30:00 |     1.5 |
|  3 |               2 | 05:30:00   | 16:30:00 |    0.75 |
|  4 |               2 | 16:30:00   | 19:00:00 |    0.50 |
|  5 |               2 | 19:00:00   | 24:00:00 |     1.5 |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
```

Then your query becomes a lot simpler

```
SELECT *

  FROM subscription_detail_pricing

 WHERE start_time < "20:00:00"
   AND end_time > "16:00:00"
```

**Note**, I prefer exclusive comparisons, `<` and `>`, for this query because of what you are comparing

- `start_time < "20:00:00"` -  comparing the `start_time` (inclusive) with the end of the inputted range `"20:00:00"` (exclusive)
- `end_time > "16:00:00"` - comparing the `end_time` (exclusive) to the start of the inputted range `"16:00:00"` (inclusive)

As long as at least one of the values being compared is exclusive, 
 checking for equality, `<=` or `>=`, doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Hi @Arth, thanks for your answer
Like i said in another comment, my main mistake was to have start hour greater than end and not a correct 24 hours lifecycle.
With a correct schema it look like that a classic and easy query that answer to the question.
I've just have to check in my script before if start hour is not greater than end otherwise it means i've to query twice with split time to 00:00:00

Comment: @BenWa, happy to help.. kindly upvote/accept this answer (and/or Spencer's)

Comment: or `... end_time >= ...` (with the `=`)   we need to handle the edge cases at the boundaries of the range. The pattern shown in the example table is the normative pattern, specifying the end of one range as same value as the start of an adjacent range. if we intend for a given hh:mm:ss value fall into just one of the ranges when it matches a boundary, we would typically do `<` and `>=` comparisons. or we could do the equality comparison on the other side,  `<=` and `>`.  we want the equality check one side or the other, so we don't have a gap, but not on both so we don't have overlap. +10

Comment: @spencer7593,  thanks for the comment, I thought hard about it but I disagree. I came to the conclusion that both comparators being exclusive makes more sense.. see update for details

Comment: As long as we've considered the edge cases, and the conditions are returning rows that satisfy the requirements. It really depends on the specification. In the more general case, checking if a single 'hh:mm' value falls into a range `SET @b:='16:30'; SET @f:='16:30'` and `SELECT ... start_time < @f AND end_time > @b`. We'd get zero rows returned. We only get the behavior when `@b=@f` i.e. we are checking if a single time value falls within a range. My point was that we need to at least consider handling the edge cases. i.e. for `@f:='16:30'` we should not return row id=4.

Comment: @spencer7593 Good point, but for `b = '16:30'` and `f = '19:00'`, it only makes sense to return row 4.. having either comparison as inclusive would return one of row 3 or 5. It depends on the spec, as you say, but I'd argue this is more important than covering the `b = f = '16:30'` or similar cases - how would these be priced?

Answer (score 1):

To check for overlap in time ranges, given `s` and `e` as start and end of the defined ranges, and given `b` and `t` as the begin and terminate of the range we want to compare,  normally this condition

```
 b <= e AND t > s
```

is sufficient to check for an overlap. But that only works for `b<t` and `s<e`. In the scenario presented, there's a wrinkle with the "wrap", row id=4, with `e` (end_time) before the `s` (start_time).

---

One approach to fixing the problem would to store only rows where `start_time` is less than `end_time`.

We could accomplish that by breaking row `id=4` into two rows

```
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
| id | subscription_id | start_time | end_time | pricing |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
|  4 |               2 | 19:00:00   | 24:00:00 |     1.5 |
|  5 |               2 | 00:00:00   | 05:30:00 |     1.5 |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
```

Similarly, row `id=1` could be specified as

```
|  1 |               1 | 00:00:00   | 24:00:00 |     1.5 |
```

or, if there's some reason we need 22:00:00 as a start, we can break it into two ranges

```
| 1a  |              1 | 22:00:00   | 24:00:00 |     1.5 |
| 1b  |              1 | 00:00:00   | 22:00:00 |     1.5 |
```

With that approach:

```
SET @bt := '16:00:00' ;
SET @tt := '20:00:00' ;

SELECT sdp.id
     , sdp.start_time
     , sdp.end_time
     , sdp.pricing
     , ( TIME(@bt) <= sdp.end_time AND TIME(@tt) > sdp.start_time ) AS overlap
  FROM sdp
 WHERE sdp.subscription_id = 2
```

returns:

```
  id  start_time  end_time   pricing  overlap  
----  ----------  ---------  -------  -------
   2  05:30:00.0  16:30:00.0    0.75        1
   3  16:30:00.0  19:00:00.0    0.50        1
   4  19:00:00.0  24:00:00.0    1.50        1
   5  00:00:00.0  05:30:00.0    1.50        0
```

---

**backwards/wrap range overlap**

If we have to handle the backwards range overlap, with the end_time before the start_time, then it seems like we can negate the same condition we used for the forward check, and add the check if the range is forward or backwards.

```
SELECT sdp.id
     , sdp.start_time
     , sdp.end_time
     , sdp.pricing
     ,     (sdp.start_time < sdp.end_time AND ( TIME(@bt) <= sdp.end_time AND TIME(@tt) > sdp.start_time )) AS f_overlap
     , NOT (sdp.start_time < sdp.end_time AND ( TIME(@bt) <= sdp.end_time AND TIME(@tt) > sdp.start_time )) AS b_overlap
  FROM sdp
 WHERE sdp.subscription_id = 2
```

With the rows as shown in the original (with slight adjustment of end_time to be the first second outside of the range)...

```
  id  start_time  end_time    pricing  f_overlap  b_overlap  
----  ----------  ----------  -------  ---------  ---------
   2  05:30:00.0  16:30:00.0  0.75             1          0
   3  16:30:00.0  19:00:00.0  0.50             1          0
   4  19:00:00.0  05:30:00.0  1.50             0          1
```

The conditions we want to test are included in the SELECT list, that allows us to better see what is happening. We could also return the @bt and @tt in the same row.

Once we have those conditions tested, we can flip them down into the `WHERE` clause.

We need to `OR` those two conditions, because we have an overlap if either condition is true.

```
SELECT sdp.id
     , sdp.start_time
     , sdp.end_time
     , sdp.pricing
  FROM sdp
 WHERE sdp.subscription_id = 2
   AND (     (sdp.start_time < sdp.end_time AND ( TIME(@bt) <= sdp.end_time AND TIME(@tt) > sdp.start_time ))
      OR NOT (sdp.start_time < sdp.end_time AND ( TIME(@bt) <= sdp.end_time AND TIME(@tt) > sdp.start_time ))
       )
```

NOTE: these conditions have not been sufficiently tested. note that these conditions require `@bt` to be before `@et`. If we want to handle a "backwards wrap" for those, then we need an additional condition checks and condition negation to handle that. We also want to be sure to test ranges with @bt of 00:00 and @et on or after 24:00.

---

*for setup:*

```
CREATE TABLE sdp (id INT, subscription_id INT, start_time TIME(1), end_time TIME(1), pricing DECIMAL(8,2), PRIMARY KEY (id))
;
INSERT INTO sdp (id, subscription_id, start_time, end_time, pricing) VALUES 
 ( 1 , 1 , '22:00:00'   , '22:00:00' ,  1.50 )
,( 2 , 2 , '05:30:00'   , '16:30:00' ,  0.75 )
,( 3 , 2 , '16:30:00'   , '19:00:00' ,  0.50 )
,( 4 , 2 , '19:00:00'   , '05:30:00' ,  1.50 )
;
```

to avoid wraps in ranges, make all ranges end_time after start_time

```
DELETE FROM sdp WHERE id = 4; 
INSERT INTO sdp (id, subscription_id, start_time, end_time, pricing) VALUES 
 ( 4 , 2 , '19:00:00'   , '24:30:00' ,  1.50 )
,( 5 , 2 , '00:00:00'   , '05:30:00' ,  1.50 )
;
```

Comment: Hi @spence7593. Thanks a lot for your answer.
I did not manage to make your example work. It return all rows for subscription id. Not sure to understand... What the point to have the same query in WHERE clause, one classic and the other, the same, but with "NOT" before, that mean all, isn't it?

Comment: @BenWa: there were several points. first was to _not_ have ranges that "wrap" i.e. with `end_time` before `start_time`. if we do that, then the query is straightforward and easy to understand. the pattern for checking date/time ranges for overlap has been asked and answered many times. here is an answer that explains how we derive the condition **`s1 <= e2 AND e1 >s2`**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388666/how-to-check-if-two-date-ranges-overlap-in-mysql/28389422#28389422

Comment: @BenWa: the second part of the answer (starting here: **backwards/wrap range overlap**) extends the discussion beyond the straightforward case of checking for range overlaps, and the adjustments we need to make to allow for the "wrap" ranges, with end_time earlier than start_time, where we are looking for an overlap not "between" end_time and start_time,  but not overlapping the end_time to start_time range. the second condition, prefaced with `NOT` dpes the range check for rows that have end_time before start_time.