# Select column contains date between start_time and end_time

Tags: mysql, select

I have for example table with column

```
 start_time          | end_time            | ipaddr         |
 2021-12-19 13:14:32 | 2022-01-12 21:40:46 | 10.168.100.1   |
 2021-12-03 20:30:21 | 2022-02-24 21:40:46 | 10.224.89.95   |
 2021-12-19 12:32:47 | 2022-02-27 21:20:46 | 10.18.71.33`
```

what select question I need to use in mysql if I want select rows including day for example between date 2022-02-25 and 2022-03-25. The start_time or end_time result may be earlier or later, but if one day is in this range, it displayed a record?

Comment: [How to check if two date ranges overlap in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388666/how-to-check-if-two-date-ranges-overlap-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to build a query that verifies if one of the 4 possible overlapping scenarios is happening:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
(
my_start BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
OR
my_end BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
OR
start_time BETWEEN my_start AND my_end
OR
end_time BETWEEN my_start AND my_end
)
```

where my_start and my_end are the dates of the range you want to query.